# Can we change the printer settings using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I need to print a receipt with `80 X 297 mm` size. I have this following code to print. I formatted its style using this following code,

```
function Popup(data) 
    {
       var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=250px,width=250px');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
        /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body>');

        mywindow.document.write('<div style="width:450px; word-wrap: break-word;font-size:10px;"><div class="overall_div" style="color:blue;  position: absolute;top: 0px;height: 100%;width: 100%;" left:0px;><div class="login" id="mydiv" style="position: absolute;width: 75%;height: 100%;margin-left: 0px;overflow: hidden;"><div class="login-form" style="box-sizing: border-box;padding-top: 15px;margin: 8px auto;overflow: hidden;margin-top: 0px;margin-left: 0px;"><label class="item" style="font-size: 10px;" height: 100px;width: 100px;>Itm : </label><label class="item1" style="font-size: 10px;">fdshgf</label><label class="price" style="font-size: 10px; height: 100px;width: 100px;">Price : </label><label class="price1" style="font-size: 10px;">1000</label><label class="qty_prch" style="font-size: 10px; height:100px;width:100px;">Qty_Prch : </label><label class="qty_prch1" style="font-size: 10px;">2</label><label class="subtotal" style="font-size: 10px;height: 100px;width: 100px;">SubTtl : </label><label class="subtotal1" style="font-size: 10px;">1000</label><label class="discount" style="font-size: 10px;height: 100px;width: 100px;">Disc : </label><label class="discount1" style="font-size: 10px;">100</label><label class="employee" style="font-size: 10px;height: 100px;width: 100px;">Emp :</label><label class="employee1" style="font-size: 10px;">2</label><label class="qty_used" style="font-size: 10px;height: 100px;width: 100px;">Qty_Used : </label><label class="qty_used1" style="font-size: 10px;">1</label><label class="tax" style="font-size: 10px;height: 100px;width: 100px;">Tax :</label><label class="tax1" style="font-size: 10px;">15</label></div></div><div class="login1" style="width: 25%;height: 100%;margin-left: 75%;overflow: hidden;"><div class="login-form1" style="box-sizing: border-box;padding-top: 15px;margin: 8px auto;text-align: center;overflow: hidden;margin-top: 0px;margin-left: 0px;"><label class="total" style="left: 0px;top: 0px;color: black;font-size: 10px;">Total : </label><label class="total1" style="left: 10px;top: 0px;color: black;font-size: 10px;">1000</label></div></div></div></div>');

        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

      mywindow.print();
       mywindow.close();
        return true;
    }
```

But it is overwrites this formatting. Can someone please help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbHMj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your current code will print the html before its being loaded to the document.
Bind the window.print method to the onload of the body instead.

```
function Popup(data) 
{
   var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=250px,width=250px');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
    mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body onload="window.print()">');

    mywindow.document.write('<div style="width:450px; word-wrap: break-word;font-size:10px;"><div class="overall_div" style="color:blue;  position: absolute;top: 0px;height: 100%;width: 100%;" left:0px;><div class="login" id="mydiv" style="position: absolute;width: 75%;height: 100%;margin-left: 0px;overflow: hidden;"><div class="login-form" style="box-sizing: border-box;padding-top: 15px;margin: 8px auto;overflow: hidden;margin-top: 0px;margin-left: 0px;"><label class="item" style="font-size: 10px;" height: 100px;width: 100px;>Itm : </label><label class="item1" style="font-size: 10px;">fdshgf</label><label class="price" style="font-size: 10px; height: 100px;width: 100px;">Price : </label><label class="price1" style="font-size: 10px;">1000</label><label class="qty_prch" style="font-size: 10px; height:100px;width:100px;">Qty_Prch : </label><label class="qty_prch1" style="font-size: 10px;">2</label><label class="subtotal" style="font-size: 10px;height: 100px;width: 100px;">SubTtl : </label><label class="subtotal1" style="font-size: 10px;">1000</label><label class="discount" style="font-size: 10px;height: 100px;width: 100px;">Disc : </label><label class="discount1" style="font-size: 10px;">100</label><label class="employee" style="font-size: 10px;height: 100px;width: 100px;">Emp :</label><label class="employee1" style="font-size: 10px;">2</label><label class="qty_used" style="font-size: 10px;height: 100px;width: 100px;">Qty_Used : </label><label class="qty_used1" style="font-size: 10px;">1</label><label class="tax" style="font-size: 10px;height: 100px;width: 100px;">Tax :</label><label class="tax1" style="font-size: 10px;">15</label></div></div><div class="login1" style="width: 25%;height: 100%;margin-left: 75%;overflow: hidden;"><div class="login-form1" style="box-sizing: border-box;padding-top: 15px;margin: 8px auto;text-align: center;overflow: hidden;margin-top: 0px;margin-left: 0px;"><label class="total" style="left: 0px;top: 0px;color: black;font-size: 10px;">Total : </label><label class="total1" style="left: 10px;top: 0px;color: black;font-size: 10px;">1000</label></div></div></div></div>');

    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    //If you having trouble with the onload binding to body use this
    mywindow.document.write('<script type="text/javascript">window.print();<\/script>');
    mywindow.close();
}
```

Comment: I called this function on document load but still my format is not applied @Marcus H

Comment: ok, If you comment out mywindow.close(); - do you get the format you want when you look at the popup window?? If you don't get it, You have added the wrong format or not included the right css to the document of the window.open. When I run this code I get exactly the code you have added.

Comment: Yes css is applied in that window but not in the print preview.. see the preview i updated in my question @Marcus H

Comment: I've updated my code, please give it a try. When I run the same I can import the css and the page print as expected.

Comment: i still have same problem there is no change in my print preview@Marcus H

Comment: ok, if you comment out mywindow.close(); and when the popup shows hit F12 and inspect the head element. Does it has a reference to main.css? If you click on the main.css does the reference get the right path?

Comment: I followed your instruction and css is linked with my document. Now I get a empty print preview@Marcus H